# How would I implement an array that stores multiple data points for each element without structs?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

This is for an assignment, so I don't need code or an exact answer, just a guide in the right direction. The problem states to create an array of student structs. The structs would hold basic student information. That part I can easily do. The next part of the question says to "write the same program without using structs". How on earth would I do this? The only somewhat crazy idea I can come up with would be to use a multidimensional array, in which each row corresponded to a student and each column held the varying information for that student. Is there a better way to do this? I am writing in C++

Comment: It sounds like your teacher wants a separate array for each of the members in the struct.  In other words, he wants you to pretend that you're writing Fortran, where you really can't do better than "parallel arrays" for logically related items.

Comment: @arayq2  Ah, so like there is an array named student1, with student1[0]=theirName, etc. And repeat for each student? Or by members of the struct, an array for student names and an array for student ages?

Comment: Let's say you have struct student { string name; int age; }; and then student students[20];  That would be an array of 20 student structs.  Now forget about the structs and declare string name[20]; and int age[20]; and work with those arrays in parallel, that is work with name[i] and age[i] instead of students[i].name and students[i].age, just like we used to do things in the 1970s.

Comment: Awesome. I have a feeling that is what is wanted since the chapter this problem is from is comparing programming langauges and you mentioned Fortran. Thanks!

Comment: I hasten to add, if I've guessed your teacher's intentions correctly, you may need a new teacher.  I still see "parallel arrays" in production code today, and it's _always_ a complete horror show.  Please unlearn this "technique" at your earliest convenience!

Comment: Theoretically if there are significant differences between the size/align requirements of each field, parallel arrays would be useful. In practice, I have never encountered any code worth optimizing at that level.